# Create DataTable via Linq

Tags: linq

Please advice how I can create a datatable with the following source:

```
public class MyClass : IEquatable<My>
{
  public int field1 { get; set; }
  public int field2 { get; set; }
}

List<MyClass> lst = new List<MyClass>();

MyClass e = new MyClass;
e.field1 = 1;
e.field2 = 2;

lst.Add(e);
```

How I can create the datatable for field1 and field2 values using Linq ?

Comment: A DT is a special kind of pre-LINQ object representing a "loosely" typed matrix. There might be a reflective solution (not strictly related to LINQ), but just create the DT (and the column definitions) then add new rows with the values (an array can be assigned per row in column order). Since a DT is a mutative structure, I would recommend a standard `foreach` to add the new rows. (Reflective approaches will do the same, but extract the names/types from a given source automagically.)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't use any cool LINQ specific code but you can create a DataTable, add the Columns, loop over the List you've populated

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("field1");
dt.Columns.Add("Field2");

lst.ForEach(l => {

var dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr[0] = l.field1;
    dr[1] = l.field2;

    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
});
```

Comment: I think this is an icky use of `ForEach` - although this is preference! I never use it, prefering `foreach` for the syntax and showing that it's *not* a pure operation like one might expect from most other LINQ usages. That being said, this shows the crux of the approach (might want to type the columns, and can assign by array).

Answer (score 1):

You can Use [CopyToDataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable.aspx) extension Method. Check MSDN article [How to: Implement CopyToDataTable Where the Generic Type T Is Not a DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx)

```
DataTable table = lst.CopyToDataTable();
```